# CV still not graduated

Tags: cv, italy

I'm doing a CV for PhD application but still I'm not graduated. How can I say that My starting mark before final dissertation are full marks?

Comment: What is a "starting mark," and what are "full marks"?

Comment: In Italy exam marks are given on a total of 30 (an exam is passed if you get at least 18/30). The final mark of your degree is given by the average of your exams rescaled in such a way that the maximum became 110. Then your dissertation can modify this mark according to different rules, and you can also get the honors thanks to that. With "starting mark" I mean the rescaled average of my exams without considering the thesis contribution, whether with "full marks" I mean maximum ones (obviously without honors). If there exist better terms for saying that, please tell me.

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with this system so I don't have any answers for you on phrasing or your CV. Good luck though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd put the number of credit points you already have as well as your current weighted GPA (in /30, of course. The conversion in /110 may be misleading, especially for potential employers outside Italy, who may be unaware of the fact that, in the Italian system, the thesis mark is **added** to the weighted GPA, and thus read the grade as "final".)

Answer (score 0):

Give your current grade, clearly labelled as such. For example:

> Current marks: 30/30

Or if the thesis grade can significantly alter your score, you could write:

> Current marks (pending thesis grade): 30/30